# Is it possible to Secure a Net Core Worker Service aka Windows Service with a "real" Certificate?

Tags: asp.net-core, https, certificate, windows-services, self-signed-certificate

We have some Hosted Windows Services using net core (3.1 and later) and a self signed Certificates that we ship to customers.

These Services run on local servers and are listening on localhost:someports and have mostly rest Apis so the certificates are no problem on that side because we can validate them via code.

But some of them will get customer facing Status Frontend Uis where the browser will show the big "self signed certificate is bad" message which the user has to accept and don't look that nice overall.

So is it possible to use a "real" certificate for such services to use https without that hassle?

Comment: What does `"real"` mean? A certificate signed by a proper certificate authority? If so, I don't see why not - shouldn't be much different from what you've already done.

Comment: @Xerillio yes thats what i meant. 
Arent thoose bound to whatever "www.url.com" they are registered to?

Comment: Yes, it's typically registered to a domain (often without a subdomain I believe - so not the "www" part in your example but a "*" instead). You can also use it for multiple domains just like StackExchange does for its sites - take a look at the certificate in your browser and look under "Subject Alt Names". You'll also see it's the same certificate used both on SO and e.g. https://superuser.com/ if you go there.